# Permission for session directory

Tags: php, session, permissions

I am facing an issue with my server that php session is not able to store data.
Now, I changed my session directory permission to 777.
Can any one confirm that this permission is correct and secure?

Comment: "Correct" and "Secure" depends on the context. Basically it's always a bad idea to have a directory with `777`. If it works, it's correct but it's not secure. Set it to something like 755 if the folder is owned by the webserver process or 775 if it's owned by a group the webserserver user is in.

Comment: [http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Unix/unixpermissions.php] check this

Comment: @jugnu that is terrible advice. And the link you posted is just a generic description of how permissions work, completely useless for the question at hand.

Comment: See e.g. [What permissions / ownership to set on PHP Sessions Folder when running FastCGI / PHP-FPM (as user “nobody”)?](http://serverfault.com/questions/70634/what-permissions-ownership-to-set-on-php-sessions-folder-when-running-fastcgi) 777 is highly dangerous, as any user on the server could hijack running sessions.

Comment: @Pekka if 777 is not the right permission, then what permission should I use? Is changing the group and owner to nobody safe?

Comment: i did not advise anything,i said it seems right to me(i may be wrong, as i am also learning) and that link is just for knowing permission codes(who ever write an answer or comment here does not means he/she is a super hero like you :))

Comment: @jugnu It's not about being a super hero - I wouldn't know the right answer to this without doing a lot of research. But saying "it seems right" without really knowing is dangerous IMO, especially in security questions. When you do, at least add the information that you don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

As user prehfeldt said, "correct and secure" depends on the context. The important thing is that as I understand from your question, you have customized the directory where php sessions are saved. This is a good practice, especially if you are on shared hosting. Since the sessions directory is not placed in your public folders (making it accessible to anyone), the permissions you set should not be a problem.

Anyway, minimum permissions needed are read/write permissions for the user that represents the server (usually for apache apache runs with owner & group www-data, but this might not be the case with all linux servers distributions).